# How correctly upload base64 encoded image to file server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, encoding

I'm using [CropIt](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?o7vgWT7J) JQuery plugin to crop and upload photo. Plugin after selecting photo returning base64 encoded image. Like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA....`

I'm using Ajax to send It to PHP in following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {      
        $('.image-editor').cropit('imageSrc', 'images/' + data );
        $('#change').css("background-image", "url('images/" + data + "')");
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

How correctly validate and store image to file server via PHP?

For now I'm using PHP like this and It's working, but as I've read before, this method is not safe and there is no any validations:

```
function decode ($code) {
    list($type, $code) = explode(';', $code);
    list(, $code)      = explode(',', $code);
    $code = base64_decode($code);

    file_put_contents('images/filename.jpg', $code); // there filename static for example
}
$testdata = $_POST["image-data"];
decode($testdata);

echo "filename.jpg";
```

Should I use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `file_put_contents()`? But how could I achieve It with base64 encoded image?

I seen way to validate files like this, but I don't know how to use it with base64 encoded images:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } 
    else {
        $fileName = $temp[0].".".$temp[1];
        $temp[0] = rand(0, 3000); //Set to random number
        $fileName;

        if (file_exists("../img/imageDirectory/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "../img/imageDirectory/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Comment: What kind of safety are you concerned about?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I've read similar SO questions and seen comment that better to use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `file_put_contents()` that because `move_uploaded_file()` checks if It is file at all or something like that, also said that's more safer way to upload. Really, I don't know if It's true.

Comment: You send simple POST data (with data:url). You don't send and files and that's why can't use `move_uploaded_file()`. In this case you can only check data-type (mime, given in this string) and save decoded data to a file. Of course, you can also check save image type with given.

Comment: @Vitaly could you provide an example of validation using `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: Save decoded data to a temporary file and call `getimagesize` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). Compare mimes. In addition you can check return values of functions `getimagesize` (FALSE on failure) and `base64_decode` (FALSE on failure). After pass validation you can just move that file to a storage directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$encoded = $_POST['image-data'];
$exp = explode(',', $encoded);
$data = base64_decode($exp[1]);
$file = 'images/filename.jpg';
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```